# Colour area of Polygon in ggplot based on a threshold value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that I plot using the geom_polygon in ggplot (data pasted at the end).

```
# GGplot: anomaly for ONI region 3.4 --------------------------------------
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = onisoiquimalypense3, mapping = aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_polygon(linetype = 1, fill = "darkgray", alpha= 1) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_abline(intercept = c(-0.5, 0.5), slope = 0,linetype = 2) + 
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("3-Month Oceanic Niño Index (ONI)")
```

Which gives [image]

I'd like to have parts of the area of the polygon to be coloured red if the polygon crosses 0.5 (dashed line) and colour blue if it crosses -0.5 (see the pointed parts).

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534603/r-draw-a-polygon-with-conditional-colour), but for ggplot. Is there an automatic way to set that in ggplot?

## Data

```
## Reading data ------------------------------------------------------------
# Data from https://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_v5.php
onisoiquimalypense3 = structure(list(Year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
                                              2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                                              2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                                              2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                              2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
                                              2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 
                                              2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
                                              2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
                                              2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
                                              2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L
), 
name = c("DJF", "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", 
         "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", "SON", "OND", "NDJ", "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", 
         "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", "SON", "OND", "NDJ", 
         "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", 
         "SON", "OND", "NDJ", "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", 
         "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", "SON", "OND", "NDJ", "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", 
         "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", "SON", "OND", "NDJ", 
         "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", 
         "SON", "OND", "NDJ", "DJF", "JFM", "FMA", "MAM", "AMJ", "MJJ", 
         "JJA", "JAS", "ASO", "SON", "OND", "NDJ", "NDJ", "NDJ"), 
value = c(0, 
          2.5, 2.1, 1.6, 0.9, 0.4, -0.1, -0.4, -0.5, -0.6, -0.7, -0.7, 
          -0.6, -0.3, -0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, -0.1, -0.4, -0.7, 
          -0.8, -1, -0.9, -0.9, -0.7, -0.5, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 
          0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 
          0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, -0.1, -0.3, -0.4, -0.6, -0.9, -1.2, 
          -1.3, -1.2, -1, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.5, -0.4, -0.4, -0.5, -0.7, 
          -0.8, -1, -1, -1, -0.9, -1, -1.1, -1, -0.9, -0.8, -0.9, -1, -1, 
          -0.9, -0.8, 0, 0),
month.mean = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
               "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "12", "12"), 
date = structure(c(16801, 
                   16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 
                   17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 
                   17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 
                   17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 
                   17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 
                   18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 
                   18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 
                   18718, 18748, 18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18962, 
                   18993, 19024, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 
                   19266, 19297, 19327, 19327, 19327), class = "Date"), 
elnlan = c("El Nino", 
           "El Nino", "El Nino", "El Nino", "El Nino", "none", "none", "none", 
           "none", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "none", "none", 
           "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "La Nina", 
           "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "none", 
           "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "El Nino", "El Nino", 
           "El Nino", "El Nino", "El Nino", "El Nino", "El Nino", "none", 
           "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", 
           "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "La Nina", "La Nina", 
           "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", 
           "La Nina", "none", "none", "none", "none", "La Nina", "La Nina", 
           "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", 
           "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", 
           "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                       -87L),
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Edit

I did try some solutions and the closest I could get is getting 3 layers.

```
my.lev = .5
my.lev2 = -.5
ggplot(data = onisoiquimalypense3, mapping = aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  # geom_area(aes(fill=col)) +
  geom_polygon(linetype = 1, fill = "darkgray", alpha= 1) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(
      ymin = my.lev, ymax = ifelse(value >= my.lev, value, my.lev),
    ), fill = "blue") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(
      ymax = my.lev2, ymin = ifelse(value >= my.lev2, my.lev2, value)
    ), fill = "red") +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_abline(intercept = c(-0.5, 0.5), slope = 0,linetype = 2) + 
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("3-Month Oceanic Niño Index (ONI)")
```

But for some reason, the alignment between the 2 polygons (see black circles in the attached image) is not great. Is there a way to make it better looking (overlapping: so that *only* the colour changes)

[image]

Comment: This may help, particularly the first answer using `ggh4x::stat_difference()`: [How to fill with different colors between two lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135962/how-to-fill-with-different-colors-between-two-lines-originally-fill-geom-poly)

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work with ggh4x, maybe you have an idea? When I used `[...] ggh4x::stat_difference(aes(ymin = c(-0.5), ymax = value)) +  geom_line(aes(y = value)) + [...]` I got this Error in `ggh4x::stat_difference()`: ! Problem while converting geom to grob. ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer. Caused by error in `draw_group()`: ! Aesthetics can not vary along a ribbon Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you mentioned in the comment when using `ggh4x::stat_difference` is that your data contains some duplicated (start and end) dates (which you probably added for the polygon). Drop these for `ggh4x::stat_difference()` and the code should work fine. Additionally I added the adjustments to get right colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

my.lev <- .5
my.lev2 <- -.5

# Drop duplicated values per date
onisoiquimalypense4 <- onisoiquimalypense3 |>
  dplyr::add_count(date) |>
  dplyr::filter(n == 1 | abs(value) > 0)

ggplot(data = onisoiquimalypense3, mapping = aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_polygon(linetype = 1, fill = "darkgray", alpha = 1) +
  ggh4x::stat_difference(data = onisoiquimalypense4, aes(
    ymin = my.lev, ymax = value,
    fill = after_stat(dplyr::if_else(sign != "+", NA, sign))
  )) +
  ggh4x::stat_difference(data = onisoiquimalypense4, aes(
    ymin = my.lev2, ymax = value,
    fill = after_stat(dplyr::if_else(sign != "-", NA, sign))
  )) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("-" = "red", "+" = "blue"), na.value = "transparent", guide = "none") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_abline(intercept = c(-0.5, 0.5), slope = 0, linetype = 2) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("3-Month Oceanic Niño Index (ONI)")
```

[image]